# problem with va_arg()

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

I want to wirte a function with variable arguments in this way:

```
static void configElement(U32 localFaultId,
                          char* name,
                          U32  report,
                          U32  localId,
                          U32  detectTime,
                          U32  ceaseTime,...)
{
  U32 i = 0;
  U32 tmpNo = 0;
  va_list ap;

  if (nofFaults >= MAX_NOF_LOCAL_FAULTS)
  {
    //something here
    return;
  }
  else
  {

    faultList[nofFaults].ceaseTime  = ceaseTime;

    va_start(ap, ceaseTime);
    tmpNo = va_arg(ap, U32);
    while ((tmpNo!= END_MARK) && (i < MAX_NOF_DEPEND))
    {
      faultList[nofFaults].dependList[i++].faultNo = tmpNo;
    }


    faultList[nofFaults].dependList[i].faultNo = END_MARK;
    /* Finish by increment nofFaults parameter */
    va_end(ap);
    nofFaults++;
  }
}
```

However, I got the error msg when compiling this code:

```
fault_manager.cc:3344: error: expected primary-expression before ',' token
fault_manager.cc:3387: error: expected primary-expression before 'U32'
fault_manager.cc:3387: error: expected `)' before 'U32'
fault_manager.cc:3387: error: expected `)' before ';' token
fault_manager.cc:3387: error: expected `)' before ';' token
```

I have no idea what is going wrong here. My platform is Windows, and I'm using cygwin+Eclipse(CDT). The version of gcc is 4.1.1.

Any idea will be appreciated much!

Comment: It looks like the compiler does not know what U32 is. Did you include all necessary headers?

Comment: You may want to make that an answer, @Peter, it's almost certainly correct.

Comment: Done. At first i wasn't sure, since the OP mentoined va_args(), but saw no problem there...

Comment: Hi,guys,thanks for your reply. I replaced the U32 with int but still can not pass the compilation. Then I add the -v option to gcc and found out it's using the ose supplied "stdarg.h", not the cygwin one. I solved this problem by correct the include file path.

I still found include file path in CDT very tricky. Really don't know how Eclipse CDT search the include file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the compiler does not know what U32 is. Did you include all necessary headers?

Comment: Can you please add a valid explanation ?